# how to run java applications on mobile?

Tags: java, mobile

hi
what do i need to do in order to make my java app executable on a mobile (let's say Nokia Symbian for example) . Do all jar files run on mobiles???
is there a certain way of programmings am supposed to use ?? are there specific classes am supposed to use???

Comment: Symbian is probably not a very safe bet anymore...  Their market is shrinking so fast that it shall be irrelevant by the time you have an application.  This friday Nokia shall announce their new OS/platform (to compete with Android/iOS)... I'd at least wait until friday before looking into *"Java on Symbian hell"* ; )

Comment: you may use J2ME and Symbian - that is going to be obsolete or port your application to Android - http://developer.android.com/index.html (java source runs in dalvik vm) and it will run in all Android phones/platforms.

Answer (score 2):

> Do all jar files run on mobiles???

**No**

> is there a certain way of programmings am supposed to use ??

**Yes** , you need to use j2me for specific MIDP CLDC platrofm . have a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javame/index.html)

> are there specific classes am supposed to use???

You can use the classes available over the platform , alternatively you can also add the external library

Answer (score 1):

Some OS's like Symbian Can run java package file i.e. .jar files.

And Android lacks that capability.

Phones with MDIP runs .jad files that is a Java app made using the J2ME API.

Android generate Dalvik Bytecode and run .apk packages on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, seems like your about to have a stroke. Start reading some articles about getting started on J2ME, try these ones out:

[Link 1](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Getting-Started-with-J2ME/)
microjava.com
forum.nokia.com

You have to know, that depends on the your orientation of you application, not all applications runs in all cell phones, is like in computers, a Windows application won't work on Linux, unles you use a Virtualizer. My point is, start reading all the documentation you you cant, and take it slow.